# link a checkbox to an object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, checkbox

Suppose I have a table which is populated by filling out a form on a page and clicking the submit button.

The last column of the table is a Completed section with a checkbox on each row.  On clicking on the checkbox I want to change the .completed property from false to true on that object.

How can I distinguish which checkbox was clicked and change the property from that row?

```
this.addRowToTable = function() {
    return "<tr id='tableRow'><td>" + this.app + "</td><td>" + this.priority + "</td><td>" + this.date + "</td><td>" + this.additionalNotes + "</td><td>" + "<input type='checkbox' class='checkApp[]' value='" + this.completed + "' />" + "</td></tr>";
};
```

I have all the checkboxes in the checkApp array, but Im not sure where to go from there?.

This is called when the form is submitted:

```
function addAppointment() {
if (txtApp.value == "" || txtPriority.value == "" || txtDate.value == "" ||  {
    alert("Please fill all text fields");
} else {
    var app = new Appointment(txtApp.value, txtPriority.value, txtDate.value, txtNotes.value, false);
    apps.push(app);
    localStorage.setItem("apps", JSON.stringify(apps));
    clearUI();
}

updateTable();
```

updateTable() loops through all objects in my array and adds them between table tags:

```
for (var i = 0; i < apps.length; i++) {
     var app = new Appointment(apps[i].app, apps[i].priority, expenses[i].date, apps[i].notes, false);
     tblHTML += app.addRowToTable();
 }
```

My Appointment Object:

```
function Appointment(app, priority, date, notes, completed) {
   this.app = app;
   this.priority = priority;
   this.date = date;
   this.additionalNotes = notes;
   this.completed = completed;


   this.addRowToTable = function { ... };
}
```

Comment: please complete code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, in HTML, `id` attributes should be unique. So, make sure table rows have unique IDs. At the moment, all of them have the identical ID of `tableRow`.

Besides, you should consider using a framework/library such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com) for real-world scenarios rather than creating the DOM elements, etc. manually.

Now back to the original problem: if you use the DOM API rather than string concatenation to create the table rows, you can add custom fields to the DOM objects representing the table rows. So, from each table row, you can have a reference back to its corresponding `Appointment` object:

```
var row = document.createElement("tr");
row.appointment = this;
```

Similarly, you can use the DOM API to create the table cells as well as the checkbox:

```
addTd(row, this.app);
addTd(row, this.priority);
addTd(row, this.date);
addTd(row, this.additionalNotes);

var input = document.createElement("input");
var td = document.createElement("td");
td.appendChild(input);
row.appendChild(td);

input.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
input.setAttribute("class","checkApp[]"); // Why checkApp[]? checkApp or check-app make more sense
input.setAttribute("value", this.completed);
```

where `addTd` is the following function:

```
function addTd(row, innerHTML) {
    var td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = innerHTML;
    row.appendChild(td);
}
```

Now that you are using the DOM APIs, you can easily attach event listeners to each checkbox object as well. 
Then inside the event listener you can get a reference back to the Appointment corresponding to the row you
have changed its checkbox:

```
var row = document.createElement("tr");
row.appointment = this;

addTd(row, this.app);
addTd(row, this.priority);
addTd(row, this.date);
addTd(row, this.additionalNotes);

var input = document.createElement("input");
var td = document.createElement("td");
td.appendChild(input);
row.appendChild(td);

input.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
input.setAttribute("class","checkApp[]"); // Why checkApp[]? checkApp or check-app make more sense
input.setAttribute("value", this.completed);
input.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
    var row = this.parentNode.parentNode,
        appointment = row.appointment;

    // change appointment however you like        
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I've tried the code and instead of creating a new table row its just inserting undefined?  To clarify, this code should replace the return value in addRowToTable()?

Comment: @Sawyer05: no. You need to create your `<table>` as a DOM object as well. Then `addRowToTable` should return the `row` object. Finally you should append that to your table: `table.appendChild(app.addRowToTable())`.

Comment: Also for JavaScript, HTML, and CSS questions, it would help if you post a working example of your problem on jsbin.com, jsfiddle.com, or somewhere similar.